# Understanding Quantifiers with Propositions

Tags: logic

I learned that

$$p(x): (x-2)(x-1)=0$$
$$q(x): x=2 \lor x=1$$

$p(x) \implies q(x)$ is true.

But how do you use quantifiers in this proposition?
Is it
$$(\forall x)[p(x) \implies q(x)]$$
or
$$(\exists x)[p(x) \implies q(x)]$$
or
$$(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})[p(x) \implies q(x)]$$
or
$$(\exists x \in \mathbb{R})[p(x) \implies q(x)]$$
?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What do you meanwith "correct"? Correctly written?

Comment: I did mean whether if they are true proposition or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to know that quantifiers come in 3 levels of rigor.

---

- Baby level: You write "$\forall x$" and the domain of discourse is just known based on the context

This is your first introduction to quantification. You're told that $\forall$ means a "for all" statement and $\exists$ means an existential statement. One thing that you do with these statements is interpret them as true or false. You may be given some examples and told that if the domain of discourse is a finite collection $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ then $\forall x(r(x))$ is true exactly if the statement $r(x_1)\wedge r(x_2)\wedge r(x_3)\wedge...$ and the statement $\exists x(r(x))$ is true when the statement $r(x_1)\vee r(x_2)\vee r(x_3)\vee...$ is true. In other words, $\forall$ is like repeated $\wedge$ and $\exists$ is like repeated $\vee$.

---

- Intermediate level: You have to give each quantifier a domain of discourse by using $\in$

The problem with the baby approach is that it you easily forget what the domain of discourse is for each quantifier. And in the baby approach if you have multiple quantifiers, should they use the same domain of discourse? It's evident that simply writing $\forall x$ can be confusing. Specifying that $x\in\mathbb{R}$, for example, instantly increases the level of rigor. You now don't forget what the domain of discourse is and you know that you can talk about quantification in different domains. This is a definite step up from the baby approach. You can now also embed $S$ in some larger universal set $U$ (so we have $S\subseteq U$,) and with a little elbow grease set that:

$\forall x\in S(r(x))$,

is the same as:

$\forall x\in U(x\in S\implies r(x))$,

and if $U$ is a universal set then we just write $\forall x$ instead of $\forall x\in U$ to see that $\forall x\in S(r(x))$ is the same as $\forall x(x\in S\implies r(x))$.

Now, when I was at this stage in learning I had been told before that $A\implies B$ was the same as $(\neg A)\vee B$, but never really understood logically why. Consider that $\forall x\in U(x\in S\implies r(x))$ becomes equivalent to:

$\forall x\in U(x\not\in S\vee r(x))$,

which is the same as:

$\overbrace{\forall x\in S(x\not\in S\vee r(x))}^{\forall x\in S(r(x))}\wedge\overbrace{\forall x\in U\backslash S(x\not\in S\vee r(x))}^{\top}$ because if $x\in U$ then we have either $x\in S$ or $x\in U\backslash S$.

Now, $\forall x\in S(x\not\in S\vee r(x))$ is the same as $\forall x\in S(r(x))$ because it is up to $r(x)$ decide the truth value of $x\not\in S\vee r(x)$ as $x\not\in S$ is always false if we pull $x$ from the set $S$. Meanwhile, $\forall x\in U\backslash S(x\not\in S\vee r(x))$ is automatically true because $U\backslash S$ is everything in $U$ *besides* the things in $S$, and hence every $x$ in $U\backslash S$ will satisfy the property $x\not\in S$. By a clever usage of the statement "$(\neg A)\vee B$" we can sort of go back to only needing to write $\forall x$. E.g, the statement:

$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}((x-2)(x-1)=0\implies x=2\vee x=1)$ is the same as:

$\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\implies((x-2)(x-1)=0\implies x=2\vee x=1))$ is the same as:

$\forall x((x\in\mathbb{R}\wedge(x-2)(x-1)=0)\implies x=2\vee x=1)$.

You can see that the last formulation of this statement can be demonstrated by the fact that if you pick an arbitrary $x$ such that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $(x-2)(x-1)=0$, you will deduce $x=1$ or $x=2$.

This all gives you a sufficient amount of rigor to work with, but it seems a bit informal to say "ok, the domain of discourse can be anything we want". It also feels sketchy to go back to writing $\forall x$ rather than $\forall x\in S$. I mean, does $\forall x$ include everything in the universe? Socks? Dolphins? Adam Driver? This consideration leads us to the advanced level of understanding quantifiers...

---

- Advanced level: We settle on a useful foundational system like set theory where we only ever need to use sets as a domain of discourse, because sets are useful in modelling so many other areas of math. Then we freely write $\forall x$ and it means "for every set $x$". Now, if you don't want to say "for all sets" but rather "for all real numbers", then $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}(r(x))$ is really just a shorthand for $\forall x(x\in\mathbb{R}\implies r(x))$

This is the most rigorous way to treat a quantifier. At this level you use [rigorous rules for making deductions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference). On some level the "domain of discourse" is just a helpful reminder of what the rules of a formal system should be applied to, but the rules exist no matter what we interpret them as talking about in the real world. Set theory allows mathematicians to prove lots of results, and you need the help of $\forall$ and $\exists$ in order to do this. Set theory doesn't even directly answer the question of what a domain of discourse for a quantifier like $\forall$ or $\exists$ is. The same set of rules holds for different domains of discourse, so rather than discuss domain of discourse you simply discuss rules.

*It takes months to learn this type of [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory), so depending on whether you're learning from somebody who knows about it or teaching yourself I would not instantly suggest you learn about it, but it's a good thing to acknowledge exists. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3IPVWN-1ks) is a neat video as well.

---

Anyways, quantifiers are a complicated question and I feel like I've barely scratched the surface. I want to add some more things to this answer in the next day or two to answer your question better. But for the moment, I want to add something about each of your four statements:

1. $(\forall x)[p(x)\implies q(x)]$. This didn't instantly strike me as wrong.
2. $(\exists x)[p(x)\implies q(x)]$. The existential analogue of the $\implies$ symbol is the $\wedge$ symbol, so $(\exists x)[p(x)\wedge q(x)]$ seems more right. This is not the way you'd want to express your statement because the implication that you showed held for arbitrary $x$.
3. $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R})[p(x)\implies q(x)]$. This is more directly accurate than statement 1.
4. $(\exists x\in\mathbb{R})[p(x)\implies q(x)]$. This is again weird, although technically $(\forall x)(\phi(x))\implies(\exists x)(\phi(x))$, so this statement is true. There does indeed exist an $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that "$p(x)\implies q(x)$" (-which is again the same thing as $(\neg p(x))\vee q(x)$-) evaluates to true, namely this statement evaluates to true for every real number $x$. Even if this is true, I think what you're trying to say is 3.

1 and 3 are both ok but neither 2 nor 4 are the right way to capture the idea you're trying to express using quantifiers. Also, to say "there is an $x$ with $p(x)$ such that $q(x)$" is expressed in quantifiers as $\exists x(p(x)\wedge q(x))$, not $\exists x(p(x)\implies q(x))$ as you've stated it, which means something completely different. The universal counterpart does use the arrow. To express "for all $x$ such that $p(x)$ it is the case that $q(x)$" in quantifiers you'd say $\forall x(p(x)\implies q(x))$.

Comment: I think there’s a typo. You said in the second to last paragraph, indexed by 4. that the implication is $ \neg A \land B$ when I believe you meant $ \neg A \lor B$

Comment: @Malady ope yeah that's a typo

Answer (score 0):

So when you quantify sentences, you must always specify the domain of your variables. Often this is implicit, but in your case to be careful, you would certainly want to specify that $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Now to decide which quantifier to use (the universal, the existential, or something else like the unique existential) it is necessary to think about what the proposition is really saying.

In this case, is $p \implies q$ true for all $x$? Or is it just true for some specific $x$. The answer is that it’s true for all $x$:
$$\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \; p(x) \implies q(x)$$
Now if it *wasn’t* true for all $x$, then there must be an $x$ for which it is false, ie. there must be an $x$ which *is* a zero of that polynomial, but *is not* $2$ or $1$. (This is just using the fact that the negation of $\forall z \; A \implies B$ is $\exists z \; A \land \neg B$.) Clearly, there is no such $x$, and thus it is true for all $x$. Does this make sense?

Comment: So (∃x∈R)[p(x)⟹q(x)] is the correct one. It is because q(x) and p(x) is true for only some values of x.

Comment: no! i’ll edit my respond to be less ambiguous.

Comment: @plutlorian do you understand the logical implication? and its negation?

Comment: Yes I do. But when we mix it with Quantifiers, I may not get it.

Comment: So do you understand now why this is true for all $x$? Or is there still some confusion?

Comment: It it true because it is biconditional.

Comment: I mean $(A\iff B)\implies (A\implies B)$ so sort of. But I don’t know what you’re asking.

Comment: A⟺B is true when 0⟺0 and 1⟺1. What I am saying is (∀x∈R)[(x-2)(x-1)=0 ⟺ x=2 v x=1] is true for all real numbers.

Comment: Yes that is true. But like that is sort of unrelated to the fact that it is quantified universally. Do you see that?

Comment: But it is not universally true. In ∀x∈Rp(x)⟹q(x), you are saying if p(x) is true for every real x (which is not!) then q(x) is true. (Sorry for late reply)

Comment: no that would be $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R} p(x)) \implies q(x)$ which is parenthesized differently. It is universally true that if $p(x)$ holds for an $x \in R$, then so does $q(x)$.